# Strip Html Tags Findall + Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Well I have done probably 2 hours of searching and I believe my brain is probably just fried. Today is my first day with BeautifulSoup (so please be gentle). The source code for the website that I am scraping has a format that is as follows:

```
<a href="/listing/view" class="price">$100</a>
```

I feel pretty dumb because I am getting the whole a tags when writing to a file and I have a sneaking suspicion that there is such a simple solution but I cannot seem to find it.

Currently I'm using the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
prices = soup.find_all(class_="price")
passed.append(prices)
```

How can I target just the content with matching classes between specific tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
prices = soup.find_all(class_="price")

for a in prices:
  passed.append(int(a.text.strip().replace('$','')) # will append to the list
```

This should help.

Comment: Even with this I'm still getting the result of:
['\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$465\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$515\n\t\t\t\t\t\t', and all I want is the integer value

Comment: the `strip()` will get rid of the whitespace and `replace()` is for the `$`

Comment: `\n` means newline and `\t` means tab. `strip()` removes all this whitespace. if you do `print("\tHI")` and `print("\nHI")` it will be clear to you :)